# Flexbox column with images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make 2 images span the whole height of an image beside it. Is there a flexbox way of doing so? I'm trying to use flexbox-direction: column but the problem I'm getting is that the 2 images span twice the image while I want them to fill the space of the single image.

https://jsfiddle.net/nLsa4oqc/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  flex: 1;
}

.second {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.second-a {
  flex: 1;
}

.second-b {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <img src="https://sarahannephoto.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/devyn_015.jpg?w=1008" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="second">
    <div class="second-a">
      <img src="https://sarahannephoto.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/devyn_015.jpg?w=1008" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="second-b">
      <img src="https://sarahannephoto.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/devyn_015.jpg?w=1008" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property, like this:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/y4w16cbj/1/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  flex: 2;
}

.second {
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <img src="https://sarahannephoto.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/devyn_015.jpg?w=1008" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="second">
    <div class="second-a">
      <img src="https://sarahannephoto.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/devyn_015.jpg?w=1008" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="second-b">
      <img src="https://sarahannephoto.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/devyn_015.jpg?w=1008" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```